# ConnectionPool::Error (no connections are checked out)

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I get this error trying to scrape a website with mechanize.

This is my code:

```
agent = Mechanize.new

agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'

agent.keep_alive = false

page = agent.get('https://web.archive.org/web/20170417084732/https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~andwhay/postlist.html')

page.links_with(:text => 'post').each do |link|
  post = link.click
  Article.create(
    user_id: 1,
    title: post.css('title'),
    text: post.at("//div[@itemprop = 'description']")
  )
end
```

I also used [this code](http://scottwb.com/blog/2013/11/09/defeating-the-infamous-mechanize-too-many-connection-resets-bug/) to avoid the "Too Many Connection Resets" error.

Answer (score 4):

The code from the linked blog post seems to be incompatible with v3.0.0 of the net-http-persistent gem.  Note that Mechanize v2.7.6 (the current version as of this writing) is compatible with net-http-persistent >= v2.5.2, which includes v3.0.0.

The short answer is to do one of the following:

- Pin net-http-persistent to v2.9.4
- **(experimental)** Remove the call to `self.http.shutdown` on line 44 of the linked blog post

The long answer is that the net-http-persistent gem started using the connection_pool gem in v3.0.0, which changed the behavior of `Net::HTTP::Persistent#shutdown` (aka `self.http.shutdown` in `Mechanize::HTTP::Agent`).  The new behavior raises a `ConnectionPool::Error` ("no connections are checked out") if a request is made after `shutdown` has been invoked.

However, looking through the code of both net-http-persistent v2.9.4 and v3.0.0, it seems like `self.http.shutdown` may not have been necessary in the first place.  The main purpose of `shutdown` seems to be invoking `finish` on each of the connections.  In both v2.9.4 and v3.0.0, when `Net::HTTP::Persistent#request` rescues from an `Errno::ECONNRESET` exception (the original cause of all this), it retries only once and then calls `Net::HTTP::Persistent#request_failed`.  `request_failed` in turn calls `Net::HTTP::Persistent#finish` with the connection.  Thus, it seems the only necessary monkey patching is to retry more than once.